# sql group by values from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, case

```
City | Person           City | Person
--------------          -------------
C    | Fanie            D    | Jan
C    | Johannes         D    | Maria
C    | Anna      to     J    | Frik
D    | Jan              C    | Anna    
D    | Maria            C    | Fanie  
J    | Frik             C    | Johannes
```

I want ^ table to be like this one ^.

I have tried to say `Select * FROM TableA GROUP BY City ='D', City = 'J' City = 'C'` but then the names are not in the order as shown above? How would I achieve this? Or how do you croup by a column value and sort the names. ?

Comment: you want it to look like the left table or the right table?

Comment: Order by on city with case statement

Comment: How is D before J and C or Maria after Han but before Frik? Please explain the sorting order you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT City, Person
FROM TableA
WHERE City IN ('C', 'D', 'J')
ORDER BY
    (CASE City
        WHEN 'D' THEN 1
        WHEN 'J' THEN 2
        WHEN 'C' THEN 3
        ELSE 4 END),
    Person;
```

Answer (score 1):

For customized sorting, or sorting based on some rule, one can use case statement in order by clause in following way and execute it

```
Select * FROM TableA order by case when city ='D' then 1
when city ='J' then 2 else 3 end, Person
```

Can you try this ?

Comment: Could you please expand on why this is a good solution for the problem.

Comment: you want customized sorting, which is not natural, so make it natural order i.e 1,2,3 and sort it

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and put this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TableA ORDER BY City,Person
```

This should work if you want to sort by City then by Person, but from your output I can't see anykind of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you need to do this i hope this will help you!, 
 i used the CASE function of MySQL the solution that i provide is WHEN the City is equals to 'D' it will be the first who sort then if City = 'C' then it will be the second ELSE it will be the last

```
SELECT * FROM TableA GROUP BY City,Person ORDER BY CASE WHEN City = 'D' THEN 1 WHEN 'C' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

Comment: You may perhaps explain how you solve the ordering issue by defining the sorting order.

Comment: @pushpraj

i used the CASE function of MySQL
the solution that i provide is WHEN the City is equals to 'D' it will be the first who sort then if City = 'C' then it will be the second ELSE it will be the last

Comment: great, include the same to your answer too to make it more explainable.